Unable to build ROS 2 from source on Windows. colcon issue
Win11, x64, VS 2022, ROS2 Jazzy
I am following the ROS 2 docs on how to build Jazzy on windows from source,
when building ROS 2 using colcon build --merge-install in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 (admin)
i get the following error:
Summary: 0 packages finished [9.53s] WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)
I have catkin_pkg installed, and C:\python38\scripts added to PATH
any help is appreciated

NVM, i have figured it out, i was using the build command in C:\Windows\System32 instead of C:\jazzy
silly me...
